# Content Management Systems that comply with WCAG 2.0

Tags: asp.net, accessibility, content-management, wcag

I like the look of SIteInifinity by Telerik as a content management system. Unfortunately it is not WCAG 2.0 compliant.

Are there any third party CMS systems that are WCAG 2.0 complaint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two sides to your question: the main website as seen by users should be compliant with **WCAG 2.0** and the backoffice as used by content producers and administrators should be compliant with **[ATAG](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/atag)** (Authoring Tool Accessibility Guidelines)

A few points:

- A lot of CMS which allow template customization can manage a website that conforms to WCAG 2.0 Level A or AA and many aspects or AAA. I work mainly with LAMP CMS so I don't know at all this other world ruled by ASP.NET ;) (a big STOP is adding a form element as a direct child of the body element, for no reason. Good luck with the rest of your code)
- No CMS with untrained content producers can keep this level of accessibility for long
- Few CMS are accessible to their content producers (the Authoring Tool part), and ARIA will help a lot (in a few years)

Answer (score 1):

I think DotNetNuke has that and this was added for 4.6.

Please check from this discussion forum
[DotNetNukeCommunity](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Forums/tabid/795/forumid/118/threadid/170089/scope/posts/Default.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The open source CMS TYPO3 can be WCAG 2.0 compliant as long as proper care is taken with the setup and templating.

Here is a PDF that [describes the process in TYPO3](http://webguide.fao.org/fileadmin/templates/webguide/pdf/Tips_on_Web_Accessibility.pdf).

You can find out more about TYPO3 at http://typo3.org

Answer (score 1):

Felipe Alsacreations nailed the essence of the problem with this question in his response.

With Drupal 7, things have changed though. At least in terms of the relative accessibility of various CMS's.  Although no CMS meets WCAG 2.0 AA out of the box, Drupal 7 comes the closest at this point.

You don't get much of a sense of it from comparing accessibility statements, but:
http://drupal.org/about/accessibility

As a contributor to Drupal 7's accessibility initiative I know how much accessibility gets inherited because of decisions that were made in Core.  The enhancements to the Core Forms API gives almost any module that extends it a solid basis for meeting accessibility (both for the user side & admin side).

That being said, this is a complex issue.  Keeping up with changes in technology means that it's an up hill battle to keep a site WCAG 2.0 compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal is an excellent CMS but I have found not for beginners. I would like to see a discussion around Fully Managed Solution (CMS WEB BUILDERS) like Exai (www.exai.com) that are extremely user friendly and go with the WYSIWYG editor.